# understanding function prototype and __proto__

Tags: javascript

I have question, maybe a bit unusual, about the prototype of a function, see this code and note the comments representing the console output:

```js
function Foo () {
};

var o = Foo.prototype;

console.log(o.__proto__); // Object {}
console.log(o.constructor); // function Foo() {}
console.log(o.__proto__.constructor); // function Object() { [native code] }

console.log(o.__proto__.constructor === o.constructor); // false
```

Please ignore that I'm using `__proto__` instead of the standard `getPrototypeOf()`.

I'm trying to figure why the last line prints out `false`. We usually know that for any object the following is true:

`obj.__proto__.constructor === obj.constructor`

Looking forward to understand why this is not in the case of `o` above as `o` is an object too.

I wonder if it's false because `o` is actually a function's prototype instance (`Foo.prototype`) and therefore it gets `o.constructor` set to `Foo` during `Foo` setup.

I know this might not have much practical utility, but it's useful to understand some things.

Comment: "*We usually know that for any object the following is true: `obj.__proto__.constructor === obj.constructor`*" - any object without an own `.constructor` property, that is. And `Foo.prototype` *has* an own `constructor` property, pointing to `Foo`.

Comment: @Bergi any object has a `constructor` property I think. It's 'inherited' from `Object.prototype` which has the `constructor` property. Not sure what you meant, if you could please detail a bit, that would be useful, thank you.

Comment: I meant own properties, not inherited ones. And you even can create objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype`, so that they would not have a `.constructor` property at all (e.g. `"constructor" in Object.create(null)` is false)

Comment: thanks. that's interesting. it's strange that `constructor` and `__proto__` are `undefined` in this case:
`var obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.constructor);
console.log(obj.__proto__);`. It somehow make sense since you are explicitly telling that the prototype object is null.

Comment: `__proto__` is undefined exactly because it's a setter/getter usually inherited from `Object.prototype`, and that's just one reason why it's deprecated. You seem to know about the standard `Object.getPrototypeOf` already, so please use it! It will yield `null` as expected.

Comment: wow, I can see now that `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));` gives `null,` not `undefined`. my head hurts now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an invariant:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor === obj.constructor
```

Instead, it's just that usually people don't add custom `constructor` properties to their objects, and most objects are not `prototype` objects of a constructor. Therefore, when you access `constructor` property, you get the value inherited from the [[Prototype]] (if any).

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.constructor; // Foo (own property)
new Foo().constructor; // Foo (inherited from Foo.prototype)
```

However, `prototype` objects of a constructor do have an own `constructor` property by default, which is usually different than the `constructor` of their [[Prototype]] (if any).

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.constructor; // Foo (own property)
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype); // Object.prototype
proto.constructor; // Object (own property of proto/Object.prototype)
```

Remember there is nothing special about `constructor`, it's just a normal property which is created automatically in `prototype` objects of a constructor to help you get the constructor from an instance. But you can modify, delete or shadow it.

Comment: `s/However, constructors/However, prototypes/` iiuc

Comment: @Oriol: Thank you. Would it be correct to say that `Foo.prototype.constructor` is different than `Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype).constructor` because when `Foo.prototype` was created, the JS engine did something like `Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo`, and in this way it "changed" the inherited `constructor` property value from `Object.prototype.constructor` ?

Comment: I just wish someone could blog or write somewhere showing some pseudocode based on the actual C++ code from some JS engine, to show how `prototype` and `constructor` are set for `Function` and `Object`. It would shed some light on the confusion over how these things work in JS

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you create a function `Foo`, JS does something like `Foo.prototype = {constructor: Foo}` under the hood (ignoring enumerabilty and configurability). This is defined in steps 16-18 of [Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)